# Poisson Equation Limit

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

How to show the following:

> If $ \Delta u(x) = |x|^{\alpha} $, with $u(x) \in C^2(R^{n})$, then
>   for any $\beta < \alpha + 2$:
>
> $$\limsup_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{|u(x)|}{|x|^{\beta}}  =\infty$$

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Where did you found this problem? What have you tried so far?

Comment: What do you mean by $$\limsup_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{|u(x)|}{|x|^{\beta}}  =\infty$$

What is the definition of this quantity that you are using?

Answer (score 1):

It's a beautiful exercise, since there is no strong assumption on $u$. Two hints :

- do you know any particular solution $p(x)$ of $\Delta u = |x|^\alpha$ ? Try to use the symmetry of the data and to look for some radial function.
- $h:=u-p$ is a harmonic function. If by any chance the $p$ you found satisfies the property you're trying to prove (you should be confident with this as soon as $\alpha > -2$...), see what you should ask to to $h$ so that the property holds for $u$. Don't forget that for harmonic functions, you have the maximum principle and the mean value property. You can merely ask for some sign condition on a sequence of points that go to infinity.

This a general advice with elliptic equations : finding particular solutions (or sub or supersolutions) and using the maximum principle on the difference is often useful.

PS : if $\alpha \leq -2$, my first hint won't work as easy, since the radial solution you are about to find will not be in $\mathcal C^2(\mathbb R^n)$. Are you sure you are not assuming anything on $\alpha$ ?

Comment: Sorry to ask @LLD, but your hint does apply for any solution of the problem? I alread did the first part of your hint. Then I proved that there exist a constant $C$ (in somes cases) such that $\Delta h>0$, hence, with additional hypothesis, I could prove that $h(x)>0$, but in the end I have used a lot of additional hypothesis.

Comment: I don't see where $C$ plays a role in what you said ? Nonetheless, using the mean value property on the first derivatives of a harmonic function (which are still harmonic), one can show that a harmonic function on $\mathbb R^n$ that is of constant sign is constant. This is sufficient to show that there is some $x_n$ s.t. $|x_n| \to +\infty$ and $h(x_n) < 0$ (or $> 0$, whatever the good sign is).

Comment: Hmm, I think I misundertood something. The thesis  $$\limsup_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{|u(x)|}{|x|^{\beta}}  =\infty$$
is equivalently to say that for any sequence $x_k$ converging to $\infty$, there exist a subsequence (not relabeld) such that  $$\lim_{x_k \rightarrow \infty} \frac{|u(x_k)|}{|x_k|^{\beta}}  =\infty$$ Am I wrong?

Comment: Indeed, your definition of $\lim\sup$ is "wrong". Actually, two points :

- I guess that the OP wanted to write $\lim\sup_{|x|\to\infty}$ 
- the notations $\lim\sup$ and $\lim\inf$ as $|x|\to\infty$ in dimension $> 1$ are a bit unusual. To be understood properly, they need the definition of filters. But one can just generalize the definition of dimension one as follows : $\lim\sup_{|x|\to\infty} f(x) = +\infty$ means that for all $M > 0$ and for all $R > 0$ there exists $x$ s.t. $|x|>R$ and $f(x) > M$.

See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132499/limit-sup-of-functions in general.

Comment: That's strange. Why just not say that there exist a sequence $x_k$ with $|x_k|\to\infty$ such that $f(x_k)\to\infty$. Well, if your definition is correct, then we just need to find a sequence, however, it seem to me that the statement is also true, even if we use my definition.

Comment: The sequential definition is of course equivalent : we just need to show that there is some sequence $x_n$ going to infinity such that $\frac{|u(x_n)|}{|x_n|^\beta}$ goes to infinity.

Concerning what you said with subsequences, it is far stronger and I see no reason for that to be true : harmonic functions can have very general asymptotic behaviour, one could think that it could compensate a $|x|^{2+\alpha}$ term on some $(x_n)$. Actually, this is explicitely doable by using $h(x,y) = e^xsin(y)$ on the sequence $(n,y_n)$ : just chose $y_n$ well enough.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation @LLD.

Comment: By the way, the exercise makes no sense if $\alpha < 0$ as $\Delta u$ wouldn't be continuous at the origin. It still works without this condition though, one can find a particular radial solution in terms of finite part distributions and apply what I said. Away from the origin the distribution (which is a function) would grow just as we want, and our solution differs from that by a harmonic function, which is either constant on the complement of a big ball or for which we can take a sequence of points going to infinity on which it is positive.